# Why is a .js file generated for a .ts file that only has an interface

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a file `adder.ts` which looks like:

```
import { Operand } from './operand';

export interface Adder {
  add(op1: Operand, op2: Operand): Operand;
}
```

And my `tsconfig.json` looks like:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": false,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "target": "es6",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

When I transpile this code I would expect to receive only `dist/adder.d.ts`.  However, there is also a `dist/adder.js` generated with the contents:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

Why is this file generated?  What purpose does it serve?  At the end of the day I suppose I don't really care much because it would never actually get required/loaded and will be pruned out by any bundler.  The only reason I noticed it was because my coverage tool was reporting this file as uncovered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Official answer](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15950), found by a [web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=typescript+empty+module): generating a `.js` for every `.ts` simplifies build processes.

A side benefit is that if you do something silly like:

```
import * as Adder from "./dist/adder";  // or whatever is the correct path
console.log(Adder);
```

you get an empty namespace instead of a runtime error.

Comment: I like this answer but it’s still speculative so I threw a bounty on the question.  If no one has a better idea I’ll go with this.

Answer (score 0):

From Node.js 8.5.0, import module is supported natively. If you don't want to support es5 anymore, you can change `module` option to `es2015`

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015"
  }
}
```

`adder.js` file is still created, but in empty file. The coverage tool won't care about it anymore